# Service to service authentication/authorization within same space

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-business-technology-platform

We've deployed 2 java services on SAP CF and both are deployed in the same space and bound to the same Xsuaa instance.

Now Service A needs to call service B with the access token of the user. Service A already has the current access token available in the current user context. I'd like to use the destination service for this, instead of calling the service B exposed URL directly. But I'm having trouble setting this up.

- What do I need to put in the destination? An `OAuth2JwtBearer`?
- If using an `OAuth2JwtBearer`, then what are the proper clientId/clientSecret, the ones from XSUAA?
- When using a JWT Bearer destination, I get the following error: `"Unable to map issuer, http://gvrn-development.localhost:8080/uaa/oauth/token , to a single registered provider"`

Any help on this would be great.